# Variable indefinida PHP y Mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli, phpmyadmin

```
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]<?php
session_start();

$conexion = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","", "trigoyponque2017"); 
/*
$ruta    = $_FILES['foto1']['tmp_name'];
$destino = "../productos/".$_FILES['foto1']['name'];
copy($_FILES['foto1']['tmp_name'],$destino);
$foto  =$_FILES['foto1']['name'];
*/
foreach ($_POST['seleccion'] as $indice => $valor){
//Vamos a verificar si trae la opcion de eliminar o modificar
$opcion = substr ($_POST['seleccion'][$indice],0,-1); //extraemos la parte de la cadena que elimina y/o modifica

switch($opcion){
    case 'modifica':

    $foto    = $_FILES["foto1"]["name"];
    $ruta    = $_FILES["foto1"]["tmp_name"];
    $destino = "../productos/".$foto;
    copy($ruta,$destino);

    $sql ="UPDATE producto SET titulo='".$_POST['titulo'][$indice]."', descripcion='".$_POST['descripcion'][$indice]."', foto='$destino' WHERE id=".$_POST['id'][$indice];

    break;

    case 'elimina':
    $sql ="DELETE FROM producto WHERE id=".$_POST['id'][$indice];
    break;
    //default: echo "<center>NO HAY NADA SELECCIONADO</center>"; break;
}

/*
echo "Variable sql: ".$sql;
*/
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
if (!$resultado ){
     echo ("ERROR AL EJECUTAR LA CONSULTA");
}
else{
    echo "<center>FELICIDADES SENTENCIA EJECUTADA CORRECTAMENTE<br />
    <a href='editar_producto.php'><input type='button' value='Volver'></a></center>";
}

}

mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

Comment: ??? que necesitas ? cual es tu error ?

Comment: ( ! ) Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\wamp64\www\panaderia\php\editar_producto1.php on line 36

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
( ! ) Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\wamp64\www\panaderia\php\editar_producto1.php on line 36

Comment: Tengo estos dos errores pero en el código tengo la variable $sql. No sé el porqué del error.

Comment: Este es el archivo editar_producto1.php? De ser así, tu variable $sql no está siendo definida porque no estás entrando en ninguno de tus casos del switch, por lo que $sql queda sin un valor asignado

Comment: has un print_r o un echo a la variable $opcion y ve que te trae, no ha de estar entrando al switch

Comment: Exacto. En él se procesa las consultas mysqli de actualizar y eliminar. Me está reconociendo que la variable $sql está vacía. No sé el porqué

Comment: Efectivamente le está llegando el parámetro.

Comment: Podrias pasar la estructura de la base de datos por favor parece que estas realizando la consulta a una tabla que no existe.

Comment: Veo en la fila 23 donde tienes la consulta de modificar, (foto='$destino'), colocalo: ** foto='".$destino."' **, verifica y nos indica si sigue dando el mismo error.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que para solucionar este error solo debes declarar la variable `$sql` antes de que entre a tu `switch`

```
$sql = '';
switch($opcion){
    case 'modifica':
// Resto del código
```

Espero que te sirva, saludos !

Comment: Acabe de probar y no. Estaba pensando en declarar la variable $sql global

Comment: Ya revisaste que $opcion te traiga modifica y elimina así tal cual ??

Comment: Exacto. Está  trayendo la opción que se escoge

Comment: Y probaste declarando tu variable $sql antes del foreach??

Comment: Sí. Me sale este error  Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in C:\wamp64\www\panaderia\php\editar_producto1.php on line 37

Comment: Cuando descomentas esto /* echo "Variable sql: ".$sql; */ que te imprime ?

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\wamp64\www\panaderia\php\editar_producto1.php on line 27

Comment: Ya intentaste sacar un echo en cada case para comprobar que efectivamente está entrando a ellos?

Comment: Acabo de probar "eliminar" y lo hace perfectamente, pero el editar no lo hace. :'v

Comment: Entonces debes verificar que que la palabra 'modifica' esta llegando exactamente igual, sin mayúsculas y sin espacios !